# Doctrine 2: Not all entities get persisted, why?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to persist Feedback entities in a loop. The problem is, that exactly 1 entity doesn't get persisted (no matter how many entities I want to persist at all; it's always n-1 instead of n).

To understand the following code snippet you have to know that a **survey** entity can contain several **feedback** entities (1..n relation).

Let's say if $feedbackCount = 10 then just 9 feedback entities get persisted into the database. At the end of this post you can also see the according doctrine unit of work. It shows that 10 feedback entities get added to to the survey (so the loop is working right) but just 9 feedback entities are listet at the end.

Any ideas guys?

Here's my code:

```
for ($count = 0; $count < $feedbackCount; $count++) {

            $feedback = new Feedback();
            $feedback->setFeedback("no feedback yet");
            $feedback->setSurvey($survey);
            // Add feedback to survey
            $survey->addFeedback($feedback);
            // Persist Feedback
            $entityManager->persist($survey); // persist($feedback) has same effect
        } // end for

    $uof = $entityManager->getUnitOfWork();
    dump($uof);
```

Here's the unit of work of the dump statement:
[image]

Here are the yaml entity configs of...

**Feedback:**

```
manyToOne:
    survey:
        targetEntity: App\APIBundle\Entity\Survey
        inversedBy: feedbacks
        cascade: ["persist"]
        joinColumn:
            name: surveyId
            referencedColumnName: id
```

**Survey:**

```
oneToMany:
    feedbacks:
        targetEntity: App\APIBundle\Entity\Feedback
        cascade: ["persist", "merge"] 
        mappedBy: survey
```

**Update:**

As asked by malcom, the following screenshot shows that within the ArrayColletion the Feedback entity(0) has the same properties as the Feedback entity(1). There is no difference. (irrelevant properties blurred)
[image]

**Solution:**

See my last comment.

Comment: First Feedback in array collection is not correct Feedback object.

Comment: "but just 9 feedback entities are listet at the end"... as in inserted into the database? Any exceptions thrown? Can you provide the survey and feedback entity annotations/yaml/...etc

Comment: @malcom: why do you think the first feedback entity is not correct? I think it is... the "...9" just says that this ArrayCollection goes from 0..9

Comment: @DanBelden I've added the yaml. Yes, just 9 feedback entities (instead of 10) get inserted into the database. I'm wondering why the Survey entity contains all 10 entities within the unit of work but the Feedback entities (as listed at the end) miss one entity. No exceptions thrown. The symfony debug toolbar shows that just 9 inserts are generated.

Comment: So you can display first Feedback ([0]) and show the properties ('feedback, survey....), in your array collection?

Comment: @malcom here you go. Updated my post.

Comment: Interesting. If available. I'd suggest keep steppinbg through the doctrine flush method until you find where it throws away your 10th entity. No noticable reason I can think of to ignore a persisted entity unless you delete/detatch/remove it later in the code pre-flush?

Comment: Just put the statement $survey->getFeedbacks() just before the for loop begins and this produced to save successfully all 10 entities. Seems to me that the ArrayCollection (which stores the Feedback entities within the Survey) was not initialized, although the survey entity class has $this->feedbacks = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection(); within it's constructor. The survey was loaded and merged out of a session. Maybe this has something to do with the session merge?

Comment: That's still weird. What happens if you remove the collection initialisation from the constructor and the pre-loop fetch call. Still just 9? Seems strange a raw fetch pre-loop fixes persistence... I'm daily being frustrated by Doctrine in my job, it has so many qwerks - I wish Symfony2 would enable it to be replaced easily. That with SwiftMailer and Monolog.

Comment: The following article explaines that serializing doctrine collections can be problematic. I will refactor my shopping cart and persist all data after each shopping cart step in my database instead of session. That should do the trick. Thanks for your assistance! https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/doctrine-user/vr-FeA8BGe8