# Doctrine: keeps dropping the first new ManyToOne relation

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-extensions

I have the following class diagram:

[image]

When I try to persist the `$blockImage` collection on a **new** `ImageContentBlock` the first `ImageContentBlockImage` object (always the one with `$order = 1`) is dropped from the collection and not persisted. I can trace its existing back until the point I'm actually persisting (and flushing) the object.

The `ImageContentBlock` => `ImageContentBlockImage` relation is defined as `OneToMany`, where the `ImageContentBlockImage` object as a `ManyToOne` relation with a `JoinColumn`. The `ImageContentBlockImage` => `Image` relation is a `ManyToOne` relation. All of these relations use the following cascade options: `cascade={"merge", "persist", "detach"}`

The objects are temporarily added, managed and edited in serialised string through Redis before they are persisted. The objects are retrieved from Redis correctly and stored back into it again.

I have the following code when I get the objects out of Redis and intent to persist them in the entity manager. The objects need to be merged (attached) after detaching them.

```
if ($block instanceof ImageContentBlock) {
    /**
     * @var ImageContentBlock $block
     * @var ImageContentBlockImage $blockImage
     * @var Image $mergedImage
     * @var ArrayCollection $images ;
     */
    $blockImages = $block->getBlockImages();
    $block->setBlockImages(new ArrayCollection());

    foreach ($blockImages as $blockImageUuid => $blockImage) {
        // merge the image?
        $image = $blockImage->getImage();
        $blockImage->setImage(new Image());

        $image = $entityManager->merge($image);
        $blockImage->setImage($image);

        // set the image block
        $blockImage->setBlock($block);

        if (!is_null($blockImage->id)) {
            $blockImage = $entityManager->merge($blockImage);
        }

        if (is_null($blockImage->id)) {
            $entityManager->persist($blockImage);
        }

        // put it back!
        $block->putImageContentBlockImage($blockImage, $blockImageUuid);
    }
}
```

I have read about the limitations of Doctrine and its bad practices. I guess this is one of them? But I do need this setup to work. How can I achieve this?

**Edit 1:**
I've been digging into this bug even further. I found [this issue here on StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920442/doctrine-2-not-all-entities-get-persisted-why) This dude did debug the `EntityManager` and the `UnitOfWork`. When I add 3 `ImageContentBlockImage` objects to the `ImageContentBlock` object they are added to the `UnitOfWork` and marked for persistence. But one, the first one, is never written to the db. Their solution is to persist the temporary data to the database and not to keep in session (Redis in my case). I use a lot of requests that manage these objects, it would slow down the user experience. So how can I enforce this to work?

**Edit 2:**
When trying to create a new `ImageContentBlock` object with 3 `ImageContentBlockImage` objects. The output of the `UnitOfWork` is;

```
array (size=3)
  '0000000001fdf8f000000000117b20f8' => 
    object(stdClass)[1214]
      public '__CLASS__' => string 'Pagewize\Domain\Block\ContentBlock\Image\ImageContentBlockImage' (length=63)
      public 'block' => string 'Pagewize\Domain\Block\ContentBlock\Image\ImageContentBlock' (length=58)
      public 'image' => string 'PagewizeProxy\__CG__\Pagewize\Domain\File\Image' (length=47)
[..]
  '0000000001fdf8f200000000117b20f8' => 
     object(stdClass)[1255]
       public '__CLASS__' => string 'Pagewize\Domain\Block\ContentBlock\Image\ImageContentBlockImage' (length=63)
       public 'block' => string 'Pagewize\Domain\Block\ContentBlock\Image\ImageContentBlock' (length=58)
       public 'image' => string 'PagewizeProxy\__CG__\Pagewize\Domain\File\Image' (length=47)
[..]
  '0000000001fdf8fb00000000117b20f8' => 
     object(stdClass)[1257]
        public '__CLASS__' => string 'Pagewize\Domain\Block\ContentBlock\Image\ImageContentBlock' (length=58)
        public 'blockImages' => string 'Array(3)' (length=8)
```

I can see there is one `ImageContentBlockImage` object missing from the `UnitOfWork`. This is before i call the `flush` operation, after doing some `merge` operations and such. I guess i'll have to look into the flow.

Still if someone can point me into the right direction..

**Edit 3:**
Alright, I have been testing with the [JMS Serializer](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer) to rule out the php-serialiser problem that Doctrine has. When I debug the application I can see the new `ImageContentBlockImage` is added with its (unique) `Image` object. All the `ImageContentBlockImage` objects have their own `Image`. After submitting the page that holds the `Block` objects, and the array is deserialised from Redis I can see that 2 `ImageContentBlockImage` objects have a reference to the same the `Image` object. This reference is unique while I'm on the page and I add an image.

Comment: Did you [initialize your collections](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/best-practices.html#initialize-collections-in-the-constructor) correctly?

Comment: @Wilt yep, collections are initialised in the constructors.

Comment: Research is continuing. I'm guessing I have to switch serialisers.

Comment: Switched to JMS Serializer, but this doesn't solve the problem. When I submit the page and request the array (serialised) from Redis and deserialise the content I can see that 2 of the `ImageContentBlockImage` objects hold a reference to the same `Image` object.